# The difference between "qualified to" and "qualified for"

Tags: prepositions

If someone won a regional competition, shall we say "he/she qualified [to or for] the world finals"?

Comment: Use *to* with a verb, *for* with a noun or gerund.

Comment: @Laurel I did not find an upvoted answer that mentioned the case of "qualified to".

Comment: Hi catfour. The reason you did not find "qualified to" is that it is not used in the type of context you have in your question. You could say that someone is qualified _to do_ something, but they qualify _for_  (or in) a competitive event.

Comment: A casual Internet search will quickly lead to reports of sports events that do use *qualify to* in the way that the OP is asking about. It is not unreasonable of the OP to wonder how common/standard/acceptable such usage is, and that is not addressed in the answers to the question that this is claimed to be a duplicate of.